When using pygrabber and bleak together, the error "Thread is configured for Windows GUI but callbacks are not working." occurs
In the following Python code, whether or not the line from pygrabber.dshow_graph import FilterGraph is included determines whether an error occurs. If I do not include it, no error appears, but if I include it, the error "device search error: Thread is configured for Windows GUI but callbacks are not working." occurs. It seems that pygrabber and bleak are conflicting and causing the error. I need both libraries. What should I do?
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import multiprocessing 
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner

#This is the cause of the error.
from pygrabber.dshow_graph import FilterGraph


async def bluetooth_receiver_start():
    print("bluetooth_receiver_start")

    try:
        devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
        print("scnanned devices:")
        for device in devices:
            print(f"  - {device.name} ({device.address})")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"device search error: {e}")
        return

def bluetooth_process():
    print("bluetooth_process started")
    asyncio.run(bluetooth_receiver_start())
    print("bluetooth_process finished")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_bluetooth = multiprocessing.Process(target=bluetooth_process)
    process_bluetooth.start()

    try:
        devices = FilterGraph().get_input_devices()
        for device_index, device_name in enumerate(devices):
            print(device_name)
    except:
        pass

